# How to validate not blank values in Access Data Validation

Tags: validation, ms-access

I'm just wondering if there is a way in Access Data Validation to run if and only if the fields they are validating are not blank? In other words, do not run data validation if the corresponding fields are blank?

Must I insert an if expression before the data validation rule to do so?

Comment: Have you tried adding ` Or Is Null` to the end of your validation expression (`Validation Rule` property)?

Comment: yes i have but perhaps my expression is too complex. I'm doing two way validation with some additional rules. Or more probably, my syntax is incorrect.